# Bug with DateListPlot with ToolTip with NumberForm?

Tags: plotting, bugs, formatting, tooltip

Is anyone able to confirm if this is a bug in version 10.1 on Windows 7 Pro?  I am attempting to produce a `DateListPlot` with `Tooltip`s but am getting a odd error.

```
data = Transpose@{DateRange[Today, DatePlus[{9, "Week"}], "Week"], 
 RandomReal[{25.5, 50.8}, 10]};

Function[{pair}, Tooltip[pair, NumberForm[pair[[2]], {3, 1}]]] /@ data
```

This works fine. Pairs have a `Tooltip` of the correct `NumberForm`.  Now lets try in a `DateListPlot`.

```
DateListPlot[
 Function[{pair}, Tooltip[pair, NumberForm[pair[[2]], {3, 1}]]] /@ data,
 Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

I get repeated error:

```
NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification {3.,1.} should be a positive integer or a pair of positive integers. >>
```

Somehow the integers in the format specification are being cast to reals. Notice the "." after them.  The plot is made but the tooltips are not of the correct format.

Does anyone else get this?

Comment: I get the same errors in 10.1 under Mac OS X.

Comment: It appears to be in 10.0.2 as well.  I only have 10.1 and 10.0.2 installed so can't check if it goes back any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = Transpose@{DateRange[Today, DatePlus[{9, "Week"}], "Week"], 
    RandomReal[{25.5, 50.8}, 10]};
```

Using `ToString` avoids the problem:

```
DateListPlot[
 Function[{pair}, Tooltip[pair, ToString[NumberForm[pair[[2]], {3, 1}]]]] /@ data, Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

Or, more compactly:

```
DateListPlot[Tooltip[#, ToString[NumberForm[#[[2]], {3, 1}]]] & /@ data, Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```